# Data were collected "by" or "with"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, by-with

I feel like **by** and **with** are both correct but they mean different things and should be used in different context.
for example i would use **by** if data were collected by someone (a person or a company) meanwhile I would use **with** if I want to mention instrument I used to collect data.

I'm am struggling with this specific sentence:
"data were collected with a laser scanner"

It is correct? are my assumptions right?

Comment: [By-with — 34 similar questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/by-with)

Comment: Thanks @DecapitatedSoul for your comment, I found this link thanks to your suggestions.
[link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/by)
It solved all my troubles!